# TextInput validation while typing

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a TextInput for a specific format of e-mail address, and have a regex to validate it. I would like to validate it while the user types, with the exact value on the TextInput box, but I'm not getting that.

What I have done is actually add that validation to the OnChangeText method of the TextInput object. The mechanics seems to work, but it is validating against the content 1 letter behind the current content.

Ex.: If I have typed "June" it will validate "Jun" only. If I delete the "e", then it will get "June" and subsequently.

Is that correct, or is there somewhere else I can call my validation to have the expected effects?

```
<TextInput
    placeholder='Type in your email'
    style={Styles.Input}
    onChangeText={(text) => {this.setLogin(text)}}
    value={ this.state.login }
    autoCompleteType={"email"}
    autoFocus={true}
/>
...
...
...
setLogin = (input) => {
    this.setState({login: input});
    console.log(this.state.login_regex.test(this.state.login));
    if (!this.state.login_regex.test(this.state.login)) {
        this.setState({login_msg: "Use an internal mail address"});
    } else {
        this.setState({login_msg: ""});
    };
};
```

Comment: What's output of `console.log(this.state.login_regex.test(this.state.login))`? And can you share login_regex state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is an *asynchronous function*, that‘s why `this.state.login` might still hold the old value when testing.

You can either use the input instead of the value of the state, like this

```
if (!this.state.login_regex.test(input)) {
  ...
}
```

or you can pass a callback function as the second parameter to `this.setState` like this

```
this.setState({login: input}, () => {
  if (!this.state.login_regex.test(this.state.login)) {
    ...
  }
});
```

but I‘d usually recommend the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's actually in your `setLogin` function.

```
setLogin = (input)=>{
    this.setState({login: input}); // <= this is the problem
    console.log(this.state.login_regex.test(this.state.login));
    if (!this.state.login_regex.test(this.state.login)) {
        this.setState({login_msg: "Use an internal mail address"});
    } else {
        this.setState({login_msg: ""});
    };
};
```

In your code, you have called `setState()` right before your validation, which means you save your input before you check it. To resolve this, just remove the `this.setState({login: input});` and your code will work properly.

P/s: Since React Native has to tranfer your datas and commands between JS side and native side, there might be some unexpected visual performances, e.g: your last input character will appear for a very short moment before disappearing.